# what were the classless routing protocols used with VLSM when it was first introduced?

Tags: ipv4, subnet, protocol-theory, ip-address, layer3

Since VSLM is supported only by classless routing protocols, if VSLM was introduced in 1987(RFC 1009) and  all classless protocol(RIPv2 developed in 1993 , OSPF standardized in 1989 RFC 1131 )  cited by my Computer Networks book (Tanenbaum 5th edition) are posterior to VSLM introduction, what were the classless routing protocols used with VLSM when it was first introduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, VLSM is first mentioned in [RFC 950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc950) from 1985. It enabled subnetting the classful address ranges, so that you could actually split a classful range into a more complex network. That eventually evolved to CIDR and obsoleted classful networking.

The first routing protocol actually supporting VLSM seems to be OSPF v1 from [RFC 1131](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1131.pdf) in 1989. Likely, most people used static routing back then - as far as I know static routes have always supported arbitrary subnet prefix lengths (or even non-contiguous masks).

Remember that back in 1985, the *total* number of hosts on the Internet was around 2,000. Any network with more than a dozen hosts would have been considered huge.

Comment: Don't forget EGP (1984) and BGP (1989)

Comment: EGP only seemed to support classes in 1984 (RFC 950), same with BGP (RFC 1105) - neither has provisions to specify a prefix length.

Comment: In a pure classful network, netmasks are not specified -- they are determined by the address. Thus until VLSM came about subnetting was not possible. It a common error because so few people today have ever encountered anything that didn't support VLSM.

Comment: @RickyBeam "Thus until VLSM came about subnetting was not possible."      
 According to what I have studied and understood  subnetting was possible also before VLSM but there was the constraint (due to classful addressing) to divide an IP network in a fixed number of fixed sized subnets with each subnet having the subnet mask of the same lenght

Comment: VLSM was the first step to actually *announce* variable-length routes to other routers. Before that, static routing was the only choice. CIDR then actively obsoleted classful routing, so the old protocols *had* to be updated (or go).

Comment: @Zac67  Thanks to yuor answer I have added the missing piece (the use of static routing) in my mind  and I have also understood that the overhead due to a static configuration of routers wasn't dramatic because of the small  size of networks in the early times

Comment: @Giuseppe Classful means your netmask is determined by the address. You. Do. Not. Set. It. Subnetting *is not possible* when you have zero control over the netmask. Where you draw the line once the netmask is "unlocked" is not at issue. Yes, people stuck with what they knew (/8, /16, and /24) for a variety of reasons. (I know of a power company where everything was a /20, because the morons were running RIPv1.)

Comment: @RickyBeam The idea of subnetting didn't originate with CIDR. For example RFC 950, published in 1985 talked about subnetting in classful networks a decade before CIDR became the de facto standard http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc950.html